# Complexity for searching an element in almost complete and complete binary tree

Tags: complexity-theory

What is the time-complexity for insertion,searching an element in almost complete and complete binary tree and skewed binary tree??

Comment: What do you mean by "almost complete"?  What do you mean by "skewed"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a sorted binary tree then both insertion and search are O(log n) worst case.